# Check if all values in Array of stacks are the same or not in JAVA

Tags: java, libgdx

I create the following code in libGDX framework:

```
public class Play implements Screen {

    private Stack<Integer>[][] intStack;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        .....
    // Initializations
        intStack = new Stack[3][3];

        for (int row = 0; row < btnSquares.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < btnSquares[0].length; col++) {

       // generate integer number randomlly

                num = new Random().nextInt(9) + 1;

                intStack[row][col] = new Stack<Integer>();
                intStack[row][col].push(num);

                .......
            }
        }

    }

.........

}
```

After `pop();` and `push();` methods to modify some values.. How can I check all values are equal or not in all stacks in the array?

Comment: `Stack.equals` will tell you if two stacks are equal in size and have equal elements at corresponding positions. Do you need anything other than that?

Comment: Also, I assume that either `btnSquares.length == 3 && btnSquares[0].length == 3`, or you actually meant to use `new Stack[btnSquares.length][btnSquares[0].length]`? (And similarly for `9 => btnSquares.length * btnSquares[0].length`)

Comment: If you want to guarantee a different value in each of the int stacks, it would be easier to 1) put the numbers 1-n in an ArrayList; 2) use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize the order; 3) allocate the elements of the list to your stacks in turn.

Comment: Thx for the replying. I want to check all stacks have the same values or not (these values inside the stacks, that i mean.. not size of stacks).

Comment: The follwoing images explain what I want: 1) the first image stacks values' not equal [link](http://s17.postimg.org/wlfzgmikv/image.png) 2) the 2nd img stacks have the same values [link](http://s17.postimg.org/rpq4u5mkv/image.png).. thanx